# How to compile and run a hello world JUCE program?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, juce

I cloned https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE

I first uncommented `find_package(JUCE)` in `/GuiApp'` CMakeList.txt.
Then I ran `cmake ..  . -B cmake-build-dir -D JUCE_BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` 
on the top level directory.

It says:

```
-- Checking for modules 'webkit2gtk-4.0;gtk+-x11-3.0'
--   No package 'webkit2gtk-4.0' found
--   No package 'gtk+-x11-3.0' found
-- Checking for module 'alsa'
--   No package 'alsa' found
-- Configuring juceaide
-- Building juceaide
-- Exporting juceaide
CMake Error at examples/CMake/GuiApp/CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "JUCE" with any of
  the following names:

    JUCEConfig.cmake
    juce-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "JUCE" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "JUCE_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "JUCE"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I tried to find where is JUCEConfig.cmake

```
 /work/juce/temp/JUCE/build$ find . -name JUCEConfig.cmake
./cmake-build-dir/tools/JUCEConfig.cmake
```

How am I supposed to put this path in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATHS?

Comment: Did you also note the comment [beside the line you uncommented](https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE/blob/master/examples/CMake/GuiApp/CMakeLists.txt#L20-L27)? You should only use that one if you have previously installed JUCE to your system.

Comment: You did not need to uncomment that line; it is only meant for when you create a new application based on that template.

Comment: In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314319/unknown-cmake-command-juce-add-gui-app) (now deleted) you have tried to build example as --**standalone** project, using the example directory as source directory for CMake. That time you tried to build the example as a **part of** the JUCE. So, what exactly do you want? And please, stop creating and deleting question about the same problem. Instead, edit the old question and update information in it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev updating same question is not helpful because the error messages differ after my changes and I try different things to get something working and that results in a different scenario. The topic is same but the problems are not. Secondly, I did not know what I was doing here. All I wanted was to run and see a hello world program. To see how to compile a simple JUCE program with CMakeLists.txt. Now this problem has been solved by the help of a helpful person from JUCE forums. I will write the same answer here itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone this repository: https://github.com/juce-framework/JUCE

`alsa` and `webkit2gtk` are required dependencies which were absent on Ubuntu 18.04 in my computer.  You too may have to install as follows:

```
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev libasound2-dev
```

In the `examples/CMake` folder in this repository there is a folder called `GuiApp`.

To build a new GUI App project with JUCE/CMake, do this (starting from scratch):

1. Copy the `GuiApp` folder to a new location.
2. In the `GuiApp`'s CMakeLists.txt that you copied, replace the

   add_subdirectory(JUCE)

with

```
add_subdirectory("<path_to_JUCE_cloned_repository>" JUCE)
```

replacing the path with the real location of the JUCE repository on your system.

3. From the `GuiApp` folder that you copied, run

   cmake . -B cmake-build-dir

Above command will create a build tree folder named `cmake-build-dir`

4. `cmake --build cmake-build-dir`

Above command will build all targets in the cmake-build-dir folder.

5. After successful build, you can run the executable by going in directory:

   cmake-build-dir/GuiAppExample_artefacts/

and issuing `./Gui\ App\ Example`. That's the name of the resultant default executable.

Credit: https://forum.juce.com/u/reuk/summary